# What should I do if I see a question that "Should Be Improved" in triage, and I decide to improve it myself so that it "Looks OK"?

Tags: discussion, triage

What should I do if I see a question that "Should Be Improved" in triage, and I decide to improve it myself so that it "Looks OK"?

Should I first vote "Should Be Improved", and then make it look OK immediately?

Should I first vote "Should Be Improved", then wait until it goes to improvement queue, and finally make it look OK?

Should I first make it look OK immediately and then vote "Looks OK"?

Comment: This is encouraging.  Someone genuinely wanting to improve a question, but trying to categorize it to help improve the triage system.

Answer (score 33):

So, here's my gut feeling.

The state that you found the question in needed improvement, so mark it as "Needs Improvement".

You're then free to *improve* the question.

My hope would be that the system only looks at the question in the state it was identified in when it was submitted for triage to actually get an accurate reading, but I would go with saying it needs improvement, and then improving it.

Comment: To make it more likely, *really* do things in that order. Still, the triage-queue isn't really for doing that work, rather it's for classifying questions and sending them to the proper destination.

Comment: Agreed, you're mixing the responsibilities of the two queues and the two levels of user administration if you try to do the work "in the queue" so to speak. Your efforts are more appreciated at the higher level and left to the newer users to handle the detail. Consider it management training :)

Comment: @CBauer I agree that editing "mixes the responsibilities of 2 queues", but I think that edits should be integrated and encouraged rather than discouraged. Voting on questions in one queue just so you can edit them in another queue seems like a waste of time. This would be like giving a beta tester a program with known bugs so that they can tell you about the bugs you already know.

Comment: @MisterDood Well the example I was trying to draw was that we're the beta tester and we're handing the "known issues" off to the developers to handle. Except in this case some of the beta testers are also the developers (ie people who play in both worlds). I don't personally move between the two queues at all, I go in for one and clear it then I go off and do something else..

Answer (score 7):

I would live by the single responsibility principle in this particular context:

The queue is called *Triage*. I feel it implies that after passing through the triage queue, questions will be grouped in meaningful containers of questions. Then, another army of anon will be able to proceed to improving the *sould be improved* queue and ignoring the "looks ok" list.

Be it a good idea or not, I trust the people who put that in place that with time other parts of the process will be made public.

Maybe then the fact that we can't directly improve question will make more sense, and it may even not be felt as a problem rather than a step.

**bottom line**: Maybe we shouldn't (I know it's hard) think about improving questions in the triage queue since it is a triage queue, making your second idea:

> Should I first vote "Should Be Improved", then wait until it goes to improvement queue, and finally make it look OK?

the right one IMO

Answer (score 0):

In this situation I have been ctrl-clicking the question link, so it opens in another tab, then clicking "Should be improved".

Then I go and fix it up in the other tab I opened.

Answer (score -2):

Personally, I fix it up immediately and then vote **Looks Ok**.

Also, I think that Triage is a little bit different than the average review queue. I think the Triage review process should be modified to work like so:

1. Click the [ Edit ] button that should appear in the queue navigation.
2. While the post is being edited, it should temporarily be removed from the queue after about 10 seconds.

   - `if` the edit is cancelled, add the post back to the Triage queue. `return;`
   - `else if` you have over 2,000 rep, `go to` step 4.
   - `else go to` to step 3.
3. Post enters Suggested Edit queue and is removed from Triage queue until the suggested edit is resolved.

   - `if` the suggested edit was approved, `go to` step 4.
   - `else` add the post back to the Triage queue. `return;`
4. Once the post is successfully edited, the post should immediately be re-added to the Triage queue. All votes already made on the post should be removed.
5. Automatically add a vote for **Looks Ok** from the user who performed the edit.

Note that users who approve a Suggested Edit for a post originally from Triage should **not** automatically add a **Looks Ok** vote. Approving a Suggested Edit seems to mean "This post has improved" more than "This is a good post".