# What option should I choose when a question is improved before I choose an option

Tags: discussion, edits, triage

Random question here.. what should I do if I am in the following situation?

1. I come across a question in the Triage which is not bad but needs editing.
2. I decide to open the question in a new tab and find out someone just edited the question and made the question good (or I edit the question so it becomes good)
3. When I go back to the queue, it shows the question in the poor pre-edited state.
4. Should I choose "Looks OK", "Requires Editing", or "Skip"?

Probably should be "Looks OK". It seems the most logical choice since it is OK now. I'm just worried that I will be penalized somehow for clicking "Looks OK" when shown a question that should be improved.

Comment: Personally I would looks okay.  Out of curiosity what happens if you refresh when you do back to the queue?

Comment: I don't know. Unfortunately I clicked Skip and closed the tab with the queue and I don't know how to go back to it :/

Comment: You can't go back unfortunetly.  Skip was a good call though.  If you are ever not sure, just skip.

Comment: @NathanOliver you should be able to view your review history if you go to `https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/history` and check the "show skipped reviews" checkbox towards the bottom right of the page.

Comment: @ryanyuyu But it is no longer actionable.  That was what I was getting at.  I was just wondering refreshing while in the queue updates the view with the latest revision.

Comment: Ah.  Probably?  I think I've done that before.

Comment: I Just can't remember so I don't want to give the OP wonrg information

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/278688/what-should-i-do-if-i-see-a-question-that-should-be-improved-in-triage-and-i

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I just verified that a refresh of the page updates the review content with the actual content. So, hit refresh and continue reviewing.

Since you already know of the new content, you can also skip the refresh and just press the button according to the new state. It doesn't make a difference.

Comment: Reloading the page does always show the latest version of a post, but in other queues, it will load a different question when you refresh (because the question you see next is always partially random). Does the Triage queue work differently in this regard?

Comment: @TylerH I am not sure about other queues but in Triage atleast the URL looks like this : `http://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/id` so as long as the id is same it will always show the same post with refreshed content if any.

Comment: @DipenShah That's true, you could always copy the URL and just load that in a new tab or after refreshing.

Comment: @TylerH I didn't check other queues. For these I guess at least other reviewers will see the updated content, so there just press the button according to the state you know of.